# How does nitrogen narcosis occur?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, ideal-gas, gas, oceanography

I'm confused as to how the partial pressure of nitrogen inhaled from an air tank while scuba diving increases as you descend deeper. Obviously the pressure of the water above you increases the deeper you go. Does this external pressure increase the pressure *inside* your body as well? Is that the reason the partial pressure of nitrogen increases inside your body? Are all your air spaces and blood vessels being squeezed, decreasing the space that the nitrogen you inhale occupies inside your body?

Comment: The regulator supplies air at (approximately) ambient pressure.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this external pressure increase the pressure inside your body as well?

Yes.  Your body is not a pressure vessel and can only support relatively small pressure differences.  When you descend underwater, the absolute pressure inside your body increases also.

> ... decreasing the space that the nitrogen you inhale occupies inside your body?

I would phrase it another way. Assuming a pressurized breathing environment, the space occupied doesn't change.  What does change is that there is a greater quantity of nitrogen in that space.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with nitrogen narcosis is that nitrogen dissolves into the tissue and blood in your body - water and fats. The solubility increases with an increase in pressure. It is a physically analogous to supersaturation.
Just like in supersaturation, when the solution is no longer supersaturated, it will come out of solution. Rapidly ascending will drop the pressure and hence, the solubility.

In this scenario, nitrogen bubbles will form all throughout your body. This will rupture flesh and cause bleeding, while simultaneously potentially blocking arteries and veins from transporting blood. A dangerous combination. Never mind the pain.

I think this is a pretty straight to the point answer so I am not sure if you have nay doubts regarding this.